# Reading numbers from a text file into a dynamically allocated 2d array

Tags: c, pointers

First off, I am NOT asking for someone to do my homework for me, simply for help with a part I am stuck on.
Second, I'm no C expert so please forgive anything that is not standard practice.
Third, thanks in advance for any help =)

Ok...

I am given a text file like this:

> 4 6
>  010000
>  011010
>  011010
>  101100

The first two digits are the number of rows and number of columns.

I am supposed to read this into a dynamically allocated 2d array so I can manipulate specific digits in the array.

I have got 4 and 6 stored into variables no problem as well created the array and allocated space correctly. I just can't seem to figure out how to get all the 0's and 1's into the array. Ive been searching around for a while without any luck.

I am also not allowed to use the `[]` anywhere in my program, we are focusing on pointers so it has to all be done with pointers. However, if I can get a working solution with the `[]` notation I can try and make it all pointers later but right now I cant get either way to work correctly.

Here is the function I am writing that takes in an already opened file:

```
 void image(FILE *fp){
     int row =0, col=0, i=0, j=0;
     int **image;

     fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &row, &col); 

     image = (int**) malloc(row*sizeof(int*));

     for (i = 0; i < row; i++){
          *(image+i) = (int*) malloc(col*sizeof(int));

          for(j=0; j< col; j++){
              //TRIED THIS BUT IT DOESNT WORK
               fscanf(fp, "%d", &image[i][j]);                
          }
          printf("%d\n", **(image+i));
     }
 }
```

That is one way I have tried out of several others. Like I said I'm willing to find a way that uses `[]` first and then try and convert it over to pointers. I'd prefer if anyone could give me advice there because I am a bit lost. Either way thanks again for any help!!!

~B.

Comment: Are you sure the array isn't being read in correctly?  You're printing it out wrong (only printing the first value).  Also you have a stray `}` on the end, but I assume you just missed taking it out from the surrounding function definition.

Comment: Ignore the comment about the dangling brace, you just forgot to indent the body

Comment: I see now.  cnicutar (below) is right; it's happening because there's no space between the digits you're reading in so you're reading the whole number, 10000, instead of just the one digit you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
  for(j = 0; j < col; j++) {
       if (!fscanf(fp, " %c", &image[i][j])) /* Also note the space */
           break;

       image[i][j] -= '0'; /* Or you can go `if (image[i][j] == '0')`.. */
  }
```

Comment: I like this, but I prefer fgetc(fp) : image[i][j]= fgetc(fp);  image[i][j] -= '0'

Comment: @Akron I agree, sometimes `getc` is awesome.